# java.lang.NullPointerExeption error?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

This is my scrapping algorithm:

```
private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
         String line = "";
         StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
         // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream

         BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
         // Read response until the end

        try{
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
              {
                    source = source + line;
              }

          st = new StringTokenizer(line, "><");
          marker = st.nextToken();

          while(st.hasMoreTokens())
          {

                nameLoop:
                if(marker.equals("Name:"))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    Name = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break nameLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                addressLoop:
                if(marker.equals("Address:"))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    Address = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break addressLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                sexLoop:
                if(marker.equals("Sex:"))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    Sex = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break sexLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                birthLoop:
                if(marker.equals("Birthdate:"))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    Birthdate = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break birthLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                bplaceLoop:
                if(marker.equals("Birth Place:"))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    Birthplace = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break bplaceLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                citizenLoop:
                if(marker.equals("Citizen:"))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    Citizen = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break citizenLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                parentLoop:
                if(marker.equals("Parent:"))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    Parent = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break parentLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                telLoop:
                if(marker.equals("Tel No.:"))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    TelNo = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break telLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                idLoop:
                if(marker.equals("ID #: "))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    IDNo = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break idLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                courseLoop:
                if(marker.equals("Course:"))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    Course = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break courseLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                majorLoop:
                if(marker.equals("Major:"))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    Major = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break majorLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                yearLoop:
                if(marker.equals("Year:"))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    Year = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break yearLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                sectionLoop:
                if(marker.equals("Section:"))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    Section = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break sectionLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                schoolLoop:
                if(marker.equals("High School:"))
                {
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {   
                            if(marker.equals("strong"))
                            {
                                marker = st.nextToken();
                                while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
                                {
                                    School = marker;
                                    marker = st.nextToken();
                                }
                                break schoolLoop;
                            }

                            marker = st.nextToken();
                        }
                }

                else
                    marker = st.nextToken();
          }
        }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


         return total;

     }
```

I am planing to show an image in a webview.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://students.usls.edu.ph/login.cfm");
```

The program will first connect to a website by logging in. It will pass the content of the username and password edittext to the website and will login. It will then retrieve the url of the picture and show it in the next panel. It will also scrape needed information such as name, address, etc, from the website.

```
private class URLConnect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
         private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);

         // can use UI thread here
         protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
            this.dialog.show();


         }

         // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
         protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {



            try {

                String username = txtUname.getText().toString();
                String password = txtPass.getText().toString();

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();


            }

            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
               }


            return null;
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                    result.setText(str);

        results = (String) result.getText();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Main_screen.class);
                intent.putExtra("result", results);
                pic = "http://teachers.usls.edu.ph/student_pics/" + txtUname.getText() + ".jpg";
                intent.putExtra("pic",pic);

                startActivity(intent);
         }
     }
```

By pressing a button called login. It will execute this code.

```
public void login (View view)
{
    new URLConnect().execute();
}
```

The code in the second panel is this:

```
public class Main_screen extends Activity {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtresult);
    String stdName;

    result.setText(""+getIntent().getExtras().getString("result"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the UI in a non UI thread. The `doInBackground()` method is invoked in a non-UI worker thread.

The `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` are invoked on the UI thread, so you can use those to change the UI.

I suggest you do this:

```
private class URLConnect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
     private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);

     // can use UI thread here
     protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
        this.dialog.show();


     }

     // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
     protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {



        try {

            String username = txtUname.getText().toString();
            String password = txtPass.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

            results = (String) result.getText();

            return str; //Here you return the string you want to set

        }

        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }


        return null;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String resultString) {

            result.setText(resultString); //Here you change the text on the TextView;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Main_screen.class);
            intent.putExtra("result", results);
            pic = "http://teachers.usls.edu.ph/student_pics/" + txtUname.getText() + ".jpg";
            intent.putExtra("pic",pic);

            startActivity(intent);
     }
 }
```

My changes are complete, you could copy paste it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't issue UI related tasks in doInBackground. All access to the UI component "result" needs to be done in onPostExecute().